# How to correct AppleKeyStore failures during boot

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, cpu, kernel

I have the following setting:

```
$nvram boot-args
boot-args   idlehalt=0 serverperfmode=1 -v
```

Because I have the verbose boot logging flag, during my MacBook Pro (15-inch, Early 2011) High Sierra 10.13.6 booting, I noticed an AppleKeyStore failure. Why is it happening, and what can I do to correct the issue?  In the recent past, I had a firmware password, but for the past month, I've had it removed. I do have an encrypted APFS disk.

```
$sudo log show --debug --last boot --predicate 'process == "kernel"'|grep AppleKeyStore
```

```
log: warning: The log archive contains partial or missing metadata
2020-11-24 09:35:47.860098+0100 0x73       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleKeyStore) AppleKeyStore starting (BUILT: Oct 30 2020 14:40:58)
2020-11-24 09:35:47.862089+0100 0x73       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleKeyStore) AppleKeyStore::start: _kernel_relay_enable = 0
2020-11-24 09:35:47.862109+0100 0x73       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleKeyStore) AppleKeyStore::start: _sep_enabled = 0
2020-11-24 09:36:07.445216+0100 0x2d9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleKeyStore) unexpected session: 100000 uid: -1 requested by: 65
2020-11-24 09:36:07.485571+0100 0x2d9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleKeyStore) AppleKeyStore: operation failed (pid: 65 sel: 7 ret: e00002c2 '-536870206', -1, 100000)
2020-11-24 09:36:24.066184+0100 0x63d      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleKeyStore) unexpected session: 100000 uid: -1 requested by: 261
2020-11-24 09:36:24.110499+0100 0x63d      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleKeyStore) AppleKeyStore: operation failed (pid: 261 sel: 17 ret: e00002c2 '-536870206', -1, 100000)
2020-11-24 09:36:24.138307+0100 0x63d      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleKeyStore) unexpected session: 100000 uid: -1 requested by: 261
2020-11-24 09:36:24.162686+0100 0x63d      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleKeyStore) AppleKeyStore: operation failed (pid: 261 sel: 7 ret: e00002c2 '-536870206', -1, 100000)
2020-11-24 09:36:44.057475+0100 0x8f5      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleKeyStore) AppleKeyStore: operation failed (pid: 100 sel: 75 ret: e00002ce '-536870194', -1, 100000)
2020-11-24 09:36:45.653202+0100 0xa72      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleKeyStore) AppleKeyStore: set handle 1 as special bag -501
2020-11-24 09:36:45.701470+0100 0xa72      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleKeyStore) AppleKeyStore::ipc_device_state_transition: Device UnLock call(-501): lockstate=1, transientCnt=0, 323
2020-11-24 09:36:45.719785+0100 0xa72      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleKeyStore) AppleKeyStore: Sending lock change 0 for handle -501
2020-11-24 09:36:45.719874+0100 0xa72      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleKeyStore) AppleKeyStore::ipc_device_state_transition: Device UnLocked(-501): lockstate=0, 323
2020-11-24 09:36:45.723962+0100 0x2ac      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleKeyStore) AppleKeyStore::ipc_device_state_transition: Device UnLock call(-501): lockstate=0, transientCnt=0, 116
2020-11-24 09:36:45.742614+0100 0x2ac      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleKeyStore) AppleKeyStore::ipc_device_state_transition: Device UnLocked(-501): lockstate=0, 116
2020-11-24 09:37:05.993003+0100 0x8d4      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleKeyStore) AppleKeyStore: operation failed (pid: 100 sel: 75 ret: e00002ce '-536870194', -1, 100000)
2020-11-24 09:37:23.913302+0100 0x8db      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleKeyStore) AppleKeyStore: operation failed (pid: 100 sel: 75 ret: e00002ce '-536870194', -1, 100000)
2020-11-24 09:37:42.796020+0100 0x8f2      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleKeyStore) AppleKeyStore: operation failed (pid: 100 sel: 75 ret: e00002ce '-536870194', -1, 100000)
2020-11-24 09:37:46.917713+0100 0xe8f      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleKeyStore) AppleKeyStore: operation failed (pid: 100 sel: 75 ret: e00002ce '-536870194', -1, 100000)
2020-11-24 09:37:56.249450+0100 0xa6f      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleKeyStore) AppleKeyStore: set handle 1 as special bag -502
2020-11-24 09:40:11.873253+0100 0xa6f      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleKeyStore) AppleKeyStore::ipc_device_state_transition: Device UnLock call(-501): lockstate=0, transientCnt=0, 323
2020-11-24 09:40:11.891904+0100 0xa6f      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleKeyStore) AppleKeyStore::ipc_device_state_transition: Device UnLocked(-501): lockstate=0, 323
```